# Convert embedded JavaScript into ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am currently embedding a third-party javascript file directly on my page.

However, the website I'm embedding it from takes a while to respond so it stops the rendering of my site for several seconds.

I'm currently embedding it on my page on the spot where it will write some values:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="[third-party site/file.js]"></script>
```

The response from the embedded script is just some JavaScript:

```
document.write('<div class="value">Value 1</div><div class="value">Value 2</div>');
```

I was thinking that after the page loads use jQuery to make an AJAX request and somehow parsing the response so I can get the values I need.

Is there be a better approach?

Comment: See http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Answer (score 1):

You can place this script inside a hidden element on the end of the body (just before `</body>`) and, after the page has loaded, move it to the desired location with jQuery.

```
    <div id="hiddenElement">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="[third-party site/file.js]"></script>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#hiddenElement").appendTo("#someOtherElement");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Another solution would be to use jQuery [`.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load the script in the desired location as you said and @James McDonnell said.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).read(function()
{
  $.getScript(/* src */)
});
```

This will run after the page has loaded.

[$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: But if the return of the script is "document.write..." how will I be able to place the values in the location that I want. It seems that using $.getScript() will write the values where it was called from???

Comment: You could just place the <script> tags where you want them in your page. Other then that you're in a pickle.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this could be part of your solution. Here is a stand-alone jQuery example where a button is used to trigger a change event on a DIV. This example just shows you how to access the html content of the div and to see how to manipulate/change it. This is not a solution for you but parts of it might be useful when combined with rcdmk's and James' ideas.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#button_test').click(function() {
                    $('.value').html('New stuff').change();
                });
                $('.value').change(function(){
                    $('div').each(function() {
                        alert($(this).html());
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>


<div class="value">Value 1</div>
<div class="value">Value 2</div>
<button id="button_test">Click me</button>
```